# Grass GUI integration

Tags: c#, grass-gis, gui

Is it possible to embed the GRASS map display to a C# application? I know that a PNG image can suffice but to make the application more interactive it could perhaps be integrated.  In essence I would just be re-skinning the GUI of grass and adding some simulation buttons etc.

Comment: While this may be possible to hack together, at some point you should ask why -- there are a number of C# GIS applications such as MapWindow, which is designed to be extensible.

Comment: So this is quite a useless task to do compared to using a PNG image to display the information?

Comment: Better ask such specific questions on the GRASS developers list: http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/grass-dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have better luck with Java than C#, as there's [jGrass](http://code.google.com/p/jgrass/). (It may also be possible to still use jGrass from C# using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), but that's entering Evil Mad Scientist territory.)